# Checking the size of the attachments

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

So I have a column that is for attachments directory only. It starts from `O24:O33` and its not all the time that all of the fields are filled out for attachments. I have this code that adds the directories in the outlook mail as attachments.

```
Dim objmail as Object
Dim attach as object
Dim i as integer, lrow as long

lRow = Cells(Rows.count, 15).End(xlUp).Row

Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Set attach = objMail.attachments

For i = 23 To lRow
      attach.add main.Range("O" & i).Value
Next i
```

What I want now is to check the total size of the attachments and if it will be greater than `10mb`, it will prompt the user that he has reached the maximum size of attachments.  Any help? Thanks.

Comment: [Attachment.Size Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866906.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the size of a file in Bytes with [FileLen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278429.aspx)

```
Dim totalSize As Long
For i = 23 To lRow
     totalSize = totalSize + FileLen( main.Cells(i, "O").Value2 )
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the message first (`MailItem.Save` to make sure the size is updated), sum up the values of all `Attachment.Size` properties.